# How can I adjust my Firebase SnapshotListener limit when I click on a button in iOS?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

For my chat, I have a function in a class where I create a SnapshotListener on the collection "messages". For performance concern I limit the amount of documents returned to 20. What I would like to do is to change this limit and add 20 more documents for each button click and have the SnapshotListener now adjust to these 40 documents.  How can I do this? It's easy when it's not in a SnapshotListener but how do I do it with it?

```
    func readAllMessages() {
        let docRef = ref.collection("discussions").document(id)
        
        docRef.collection("messages")
            .order(by: "dateCreated", descending: true)
            .limit(to: 20)
            .addSnapshotListener { (snap, err) in
            guard let documents = snap?.documents.reversed() else {
                print(err!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            self.messages = documents.compactMap { (QueryDocumentSnapshot) -> Message_M? in
                return try? QueryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Message_M.self)
            }
            
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have almost solved my problem. With this code it works but as soon as I write a new message (document) the quantity returned by the request goes back to its origin (for my tests, limitToRead = 2). So if i only click on the button it's working (i got 2,4,6,8, etc. messages on the chat with the right order) but as soon as i send a message to an other user or receive a message (a new write on the messages collection) it goes back to 2 messages.

My modified function :

```
   func readAllMessages(limitToRead: Int) {
        let docRef = ref.collection("discussions").document(id)
        
        docRef.collection("messages")
            .order(by: "dateCreated", descending: true)
            .limit(to: limitToRead)
            .addSnapshotListener { (snap, err) in
                guard let documents = snap?.documents.reversed() else {
                    print(err!.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                
                self.messages = documents.compactMap { (QueryDocumentSnapshot) -> Message_M? in
                    return try? QueryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Message_M.self)
                }
                
            }
    }
```

MyView :

```
...

@State private var limitToRead: Int = 2

init(...) {
    ...
    messageData.readAllMessages(limitToRead: 2)
    ...
}
...
Button {
    limitToRead += 2
    messageData.readAllMessages(limitToRead: limitToRead)
} label: {
    Text("Tap me!")
        .padding()
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .background(.red)
}

...
```

As Frank suggests, how do I create a new query and new listener in this function and attach my message array to it?

Update :

I also tried this = same result :

```
    func readAllMessages(limitToRead: Int, newListener: Bool) {
        let docRef = ref.collection("discussions").document(id)
        
        var listener = docRef.collection("messages")
            .order(by: "dateCreated", descending: true)
            .limit(to: limitToRead)
            .addSnapshotListener { (snap, err) in
                guard let documents = snap?.documents.reversed() else {
                    print(err!.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                
                self.messages = documents.compactMap { (QueryDocumentSnapshot) -> Message_M? in
                    return try? QueryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Message_M.self)
                }
                
            }
        
        if newListener == true {
            listener.remove()
            
            listener = docRef.collection("messages")
                .order(by: "dateCreated", descending: true)
                .limit(to: limitToRead)
                .addSnapshotListener { (snap, err) in
                    guard let documents = snap?.documents.reversed() else {
                        print(err!.localizedDescription)
                        return
                    }
                    
                    self.messages = documents.compactMap { (QueryDocumentSnapshot) -> Message_M? in
                        return try? QueryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Message_M.self)
                    }
                    
                }
        }
    }
```

I GOT IT!!!!  ;-)

I'd like to thank the guys from the Google team Peter and "Puff" for their valuable help and it looks like the @FirestoreQuery property wrapper does exactly what I was looking for in terms of behavior! Thanks again boys!

My brand new test code :

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct TestFirestoreQuery: View {
    @State var itemLimit: Int = 5
    let increment: Int = 5
    
    @FirestoreQuery(collectionPath: "/discussions/blablabal/messages",
                    predicates: [
                        .order(by: "dateCreated", descending: true),
                        .limit(to: 5)
                    ]
    ) fileprivate var MessageResults: Result<[Message_M], Error>
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if case let .success(Messages) = MessageResults {
                List(Messages.reversed()) { message in
                    Text("\(message.msg)")
                }
                .refreshable{
                    itemLimit += increment
                    $MessageResults.predicates = [
                        .order(by: "dateCreated", descending: true),
                        .limit(to: itemLimit)
                    ]
                }
            }
            else if case let .failure(error) = MessageResults {
                // Handle error
                Text("Couldn't map data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            Button {
                itemLimit += increment
                $MessageResults.predicates = [
                    .order(by: "dateCreated", descending: true),
                    .limit(to: itemLimit)
                ]
            } label: {
                Text("Tap me!")
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(.red)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestFirestoreQuery_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestFirestoreQuery()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Queries in Firestore are immutable, so there's no way to change a query that you've already attached a listener to. You'll have to create a new query with the new `limit(to: 40)` and then attach a new listener to that.

If you have disk persistence enabled (which it is by default), the first 20 documents will come from the local cache, so you should only get charged document reads for the 20 new documents.

Comment: Ohh wow a respond from "Puff" itself!  ;-) So nice to have an answer from you Frank. I listen to your videos FirebaseRealeaseNotes on. Youtube every month!  ;-)

Comment: Good to hear @Flincorp    Don't forget to click the upvote button if my answer was useful. ;-)

Comment: It's useful but it didn't solve my problem, check my update...

Comment: Did you try using the new @FirestoreQuery property wrapper? It supports limiting as well. Intro video by Flo: https://youtu.be/TogxXiDmyss, and you can see how to [update the criteria in the sample app](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Example/FirestoreSample/FirestoreSample/Views/FavouriteFruitsView.swift#L59).

Comment: Peter, is the new @FirestoreQuery property wrapper act like a Snapshot listeners, update the view in realtime?

Comment: So it seems that the answer is yes with my tests!  ;-)